# the asymptotic cone of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

I am just curious about something.

The asymptotic cone of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ minus one point is $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, I think the asymptotic cone of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ minus a finite number of points is still $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So would the asymptotic cone of $GL_n(k)$ equal to the set of all matrices $M_n(k)$, where $k$ is algebraically closed?

And would the asymptotic cone of unipotent matrices in $GL_n(k)$ equal to itself?

Thanks for your time.

$$ 
$$

Comment: Can you tell me what is an asymptotic cone?